# My comment edited by someone else

Tags: support, editing, comments

My comment [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147609/what-does-get-out-of-dodge-mean#comment298735_147609) did not originally include the google search link. In fact, I intentionally did **not** do this style of link. However, it looks like I did to anyone reading, and I have no way to correct it.

How can I reject someone else putting words in my mouth?

Also, if this is possible, there *really* needs to be a notification that someone else has decided that you've said something. I'm glad I found this one, but how many more are there?

Comment: You can raise a custom flag on the comment for moderator attention.  Point out that someone has edited in a spam link.  I'm not sure how it is possible to edit another's comment though.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't think I have the option to flag my own comment

Comment: Good point, my mistake.  You can put a flag on the post itself though.

Comment: I didn’t change your comment but the easiest way to correct it is to delete it and repost it without the link. I realize that doesn’t completely address your question.

Comment: I agree that adding a Google link can appear to be  rude by the person asking the question, it could seem belittling, or worse, sarcastic, I'm not saying it always comes across this way but it could do. A simple solution exists, you can delete your own comment, but that would invalidate your question on meta.

Answer (score 4):

The link was added by a moderator.  You (during the edit window) and moderators are the only ones able to edit comments.  I don't know specific site etiquette, but you can get their attention by posting on meta (which you did), flagging the question with a custom reason, and [using the contact link at the bottom of the page](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

One helpful link to refer to in your message is [A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/238095#238095), which recommends editing comments *rarely* and does not recommend editing to add links. (Again, I don't know this community or if moderators have collectively taken a different stance.) The philosophy in that post is part of why there's no notification or indication that a moderator has edited a post.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed a moderator removing my comments sometimes, although they weren't abusing or unwanted. Moderators indeed do edit and delete comments if they feel that it's best. I can't disagree since most my comments are either **+1** or slightly **spam**ous. The interesting thing is why aren't there any notifications to those actions, whereupon this would really help analyse the work of the moderator and the purpose of those comments.

Comment: Comments are ephemeral - they are supposed to be something disposable. You shouldn't spend much time worrying about how and when they get cleaned up.  The majority of comments are removed because they are no longer needed or are distracting from a question or answer and not because they were "bad". If there were something that should be learned from a change to a comment (removing it or editing it), the moderation team would leave a comment with an '@' mention to bring it to your attention.

Comment: Moderators don't actually edit comments very often.  We can, but we delete comments *much* more often than we edit them.

Comment: As long as comments are not deleted on meta... I mean this is a forumy kind of place, we can discuss stuff here. Right?

Comment: @Mari-LouA My personal threshold for what is "not needed" on meta is much different than what is "not needed" on the main site. From my perspective, meta comments only get cleaned up if they are disruptive or obsolete (usually because the information in them has been incorporated into a post).